# Get result from json array

Tags: javascript, php, json

Someone, please help me to get only the order id from this array:

```
array(2) { 
    ["success"] => int(1) 
    ["return"] => array(1) { 
        [100010973975966] => array(7) { 
            ["pair"] => string(8) "doge_btc"
            ["type"]=> string(3) "buy"
            ["start_amount"]=> int(300)
            ["amount"]=> int(300)
            ["rate"]=> float(3.9E-7)
            ["timestamp_created"]=> string(10) "1530443432"
            ["status"]=> int(0) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I need to extract only 100010973975966 as a variable.
I am using this code to get this data from yobit:

```
$order_info = $yobit->privatePostOrderInfo(
    array(
        "nonce" => time(),
        "order_id" => $result["return"]["order_id"]
    )
);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You mean `100010973975966`? You could get that with `array_keys( $result["return"] )[0]`.

Comment: i added $myorder = array_keys( $result["return"] )[0];  and echo $myorder; said received, not 100010973975966, also replaced [0] with [1] and said remains, other ideea please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image in the comments, `$order_info` is the variable that contains the array with the data.

To get the order id which is the key from the array `$order_info['return']` you might use [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$order_info = [
    "success" => 1,
    "return" => [
        "100010973975966" => [
            "pair" => "doge_btc"
            // etc..
        ]
    ]
];

$order_id = key($order_info['return']);
echo $order_id; // 100010973975966
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hHAbl)

Comment: Can you please add the whole formula because i still get received ... if i replace order_id with key i get invalid order id... screenshot: http://i.prntscr.com/KW0ce18TR42-fnc1XZBkNw.jpeg   Thanks

Comment: Try it like this `"order_id" => $myorder`

Comment: Can you check what `var_dump($myorder);` returns? Should `"order_id" =>` be of a specific type like string of int? Does the order id exists?